# Narration In Imam Suyuti's Book Itqan Fi 'Ulum Al-Qur'an About Grammatical Error In Qur'an?

Tags: quran, authenticity

The following narration is found in Imam Suyuti's book "Itqan Fi 'Ulum Al-Qur'an". This narration has been classified as "Sahih" by Imam Suyuti in Al-Itqaan (page no.1236)

Hishaam Ibn Urwah narrated from his father:-

I asked Ayesha (Radhi'allahu'anha) about the grammatical mistakes in the Qur’an: “Surely, those who believe, those who are the Jews and the Sabians [wa’s-saabi’oona]” [al-Maa’idah 5:69]; “and those who perform As-Salaah (Iqaamat-as-Salaah) wa muqeemeena as-salaata wa’l-mu’toona az-zakaata” [an-Nisa’ 4:162]; and “Certainly! these are two magicians [inna haadhaani la saahiraan]” [Taa-Haa 20:63]. She (Ayesha) said: O son of my sister! These are the mistakes of the scribes. They made a mistake when writing (The Qur'an).

This narration is also found in the following collections of Islamic literature:-

Tafsir At-Tabari (9/359)

Ibn Abi Dawud's Kitab Al-Masahif (page no. 43)

It was also narrated through Abu Ubayd in Fada'ail Al-Qur’an (page no.229 and page no.556)

It was narrated through Abu Ubayd to Abu Amr Ad-Daani in Kitab Al-Muqni (Page no. 119)

I think this narration is also found in the Sunan of Sa'eed Ibn Mansur (4/1507, no.769)

This narration was also narrated by Ali Ibn Mas-haar Al-Kufi and Umar Ibn Shubbah with their own chain of narrators in Tarikh Al-Madina [See Tarikh Al-Madina, (3/1013-1014)]

This narration has been clasiffied as Sahih by Imam Suyuti. I want to know why Imam Suyuti classified it as Sahih in Al-Itqaan (page no.1236)? Does this narration prove that there are any grammatical errors in the Glorious Qur'an (May God Forbid)?

Comment: The Quran is proven through the mutawatir chains from multiple sahaba such as Umar, Ali, Uthman, Abdullah ibn Mas'ud, Zayd ibn Thabit, Ubay ibn Ka'b. Similarly it is present in all the mushafs and is proven by the consensus of the sahaba on the mushaf of Uthman. A khabar wahid, even with a presumably sahih chain, is of no weight against that. See https://islamqa.info/en/answers/135752/

Comment: @UmH - In the link you cited it has been stated that this narration was narrated by Hisham Ibn Urwa and he narrated this while he was in Iraq. Is it because he narrated it from Kufi narrators and is this the reason why this proves that he narrated it while he was in Iraq, as he narrated from Kufi narrators? But in the link you cited, it has been stated that Hisham Ibn Urwa reported many narrations in Bukhari from Iraqis.

Comment: Scholars from Medina who lived at the time rejected his narrations after he came back from 'Iraq and so did al-Bukhari and Muslim: they accepted it only if a backup or confirmation existed. And as stated in the fatwa a sane narrator chain is only one part of a hadith and as-Suyuti only confirmed the sanity of the chain, while he refuted the content. If the content is not acceptable the hadith must be rejected. And linguists show that the content is not true and tawatur of the recitation confirm this too.